# How to invoke a method in my theme's functions.php from ajax handler in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a method in my theme's functions.php file and I want to call it via the ajax handler.

The purpose of having an ajax handler is to avoid loading the wordpress stack(including plugins) for each ajax request..

**functions.php**

```
function klarna_checkout_sc() {
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_klarna_]');
    exit();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_klarnacheckoutsc', 'klarna_checkout_sc');
add_action('wp_ajax_klarnacheckoutsc', 'klarna_checkout_sc');
```

**jquery script:**

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/zb-ajax-handler/zbajaxhandler.php',
    cache: false,
    data: { action: 'klarnacheckoutsc'},
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
      console.log('klarnacheckoutsc error:'+error);
    }
  });
```

**zbajaxhandler.php:**(ajax handler)

```
<?php

define('SHORTINIT',true);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

klarna_checkout_sc();

echo "success";

?>
```

I am encountering a `500 Internal Server Error` above when `klarna_checkout_sc()` is added inside the ajax handler file.

Do you know how to call the `klarna_checkout_sc()` method to my active Divi theme properly?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the action hooks instead of creating a function that calls a shortcode. Call it in your ajax handler by replacing this line

```
klarna_checkout_sc();
```

With

```
do_action( 'kco_wc_before_checkout_form' );
```

Source is https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/klarna-checkout-hooks-actions-filters/